# Как вывести блок в JQuery через перменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, библиотеки

```
$(function()  {
   let reg = $('.reg').hide()
   $('.buttons > button').click(()=> {
      $('.buttons').html(reg)
   })
})
```

****Хочу вывести через перменную в котрой лежит весь блок,как это сделать?****

Comment: ничего не ясно что надо сделать

Comment: " в котрой лежит весь блок" --- в ней ничего не лежит, так как ты сделал `.hide()`  а это операция скрытия элемента, а не взятия его структуры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как то так может? не знаю какая там цель

```
$(function()  {
   let reg = $('.reg')
   reg.hide()
   $('.buttons > button').click(()=> {
      $('.buttons').html(reg)
   })
})
```